# Earliest event to get an image's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I've got some JavaScript to center images and `<object>`s on a page if they're over a threshold width. It also checks that certain classes haven't already been manually applied.

```
$('img,object').bind('load', function() {
    w = $(this).width();

    if (w > 400 && !( $(this).hasClass('inlineimage') | $(this).parent().hasClass('inlineimage') ))
        $(this).css('margin', '10px ' + (parseInt((800-w)/2)-30) +'px');
});
```

It's horrific but the meaning behind this was all originally quite sane. The CMS doesn't make it easy to specify alignment and developing it to allow this would have taken significant time away from other jobs. A client-side hack works.

The only problem with it is that the JS waits until the whole image has loaded. Obviously this means that on slower networks, the page loads, the images start loading and some time later the images snap into position. Ugly.

But the browser seems to know the width of an image as soon as it *starts to download* it. I would really love to hook into this event and splat this visual bug.

Of course, if there's a CSS way of approaching this, I'm open to that too.

Comment: I guess you could put the image in a `span`, and poll the `span`'s `offsetWidth` till you see it change. That's the only solution I can think of.

Comment: @Amaan I already tried polling the image width - the problem with that is for the first few milliseconds the image "grows" as the headers are parsed out so the code runs, finds a width but it's the wrong width. I could analyze the growth but that feels like I'm going down the rabbit hole for no reason. I feel like there should be a simpler way.

Comment: I had a similar problem once where I wanted to know the size of an image before it was loaded (for portrait/landscape layouts). I had to load it with `visibility:hidden`, and show it only once it had fully loaded. Not great, and I'm pretty sure there is no earlier event to hook onto.

Comment: @Oli I didn't say poll the image's width. That would be available only after the entire image has loaded. But since the image already takes up some space on the screen, the parent `span`'s width would change, and show you the width the image is taking up.

Comment: @Oli Added an answer showing what I was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

In browsers that support it, you can poll for natural dimensions:

```
var interval = setInterval( function() {
    if( img.naturalWidth ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log( "Natural available: "+ (new Date - now );
        console.log( img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight );
    }
}, 0 );
```

In the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cReAn/5/) on uncached image I get:

```
Natural available: 782
62 71 
Loaded: 827
```

So the real dimensions were available 50 milliseconds before load event. Unfortunately in IE, the readystate `"loading"` doesn't guarantee real dimensions.

Change the query string for the image before each test to ensure uncached.

Here's whatwg link on natural dimensions: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/embedded-content-1.html#dom-img-naturalwidth

Comment: This sounds good (and inline with my own brute-force code) but what exactly does "browsers that support it" translate to at this point? (for completeness's sake)

Comment: @Oli `.naturalWidth/.naturalHeight` is a HTML5 feature. So it doesn't exist in IE7 for example. Not completely sure about later IEs.

Comment: Pretty nice idea, also `.naturalWidth/.naturalHeight` are supported in IE >= 9

Answer (score 1):

```
var span = document.getElementById('span'); // The parent span

var check = function (){
    if(span.offsetWidth > 0){
        console.log('Width while loading', span.offsetWidth);
    }
    else{
       setTimeout(check, 100);
    }
};
check();
```

​

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B8ncn/1/). This should show the width in the console while it's loading first, and then the width after it's loaded. That is as long as the image isn't cached. (If the demo doesn't work for someone, try changing the `hoo` part of the image URL to anything else)

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of this still working on more than the latest browsers, I've cobbled together a best effort brute force. It waits 500ms between attempts and checks images to see if the current run through is the same width as the last time it tried.

As soon as the width for an image is the same in two consecutive passes, we run the centring code.

This uses arrays to keep track of things so we're not constantly raping the DOM nor are we querying items that aren't applicable (because they've already been dealt with or ruled out).

---

```
attempts = 0;
arr = [];
$.each($('img,object').not('inlineimage'), function(){
    arr.push([this, -2, $(this).width()]);
});

checkImgs = function() {
    attempts++;
    newarr = []
    $.each(arr, function(){
        if ($(this[0]).parent().hasClass('inlineimage'))
            return;
        w = $(this[0]).width();
        this[1] = this[2];
        this[2] = w;
        if (this[1] != this[2])
            return newarr.push(this);

        // We know this image is loaded enough now - we can do things!
        if (w >= 400)
            $(this[0]).css('margin', '10px ' + (parseInt((800-w)/2)-30) +'px');
    });

    arr = newarr;
    if (arr.length && attempts < 6)
        setTimeout(checkImgs, 500);
}
setTimeout(checkImgs, 500);
```

It's not beautiful but it seems to work both efficiently (CPU was getting hammered by some of my earlier attempts) and quickly (cached images spring into place within 500ms).