# Get image's natural width/height when src set using byte array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, width

I am appending an image to a `div`. I want to use the image's natural width/height to set the size of the `div` while the image is loading. The `div` should be the size of the image's width and height. Please give me a solution using jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: set div `height` and `width` to `auto` in `CSS`.. Why you need `jquery` for this?

Comment: No it wont work, After image src set image loading using bite array. I want to get image width and height before image loaded.

Comment: You need to add more detail on how you are loading image?

Comment: You can't get the image height and width BEFORE the image is loaded without separately loading it somewhere else first.  That information is only known when the image has actually at least started loading.

Comment: What is a "bite array"?

Comment: See [Earliest event to get an images' widths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883306/earliest-event-to-get-an-images-widths/11883881#11883881).

Comment: Its spelling mistake, that should be byte array.

Comment: I have tried those methods "jfriend00", But that is not what i wanted.